# Sharing one global reference Realm between two users

Tags: ios, swift, reference, permissions, realm

apologies in advance if this is trivial, but I only have about a month’s worth of experience in Realm and Swift (but I’m not new to programming in general), and I’ve devoted for literally dozens of hours trying to find a solution.

**What I am trying to make:** An app that retrieves price data from a single, global realm, /Companies, in a Realm Cloud instance, then graphs it. I need exactly two users to have access to the global realm. One “user" who periodically (every few months) updates the data (but does nothing else), and one user who can read and graph anything that the other user puts in /Companies.

**Note:** The app works as intended if it's using only a local database, but I’m fairly sure this means that it can’t be updated.

Apparently, this is an extremely complex goal, because I cannot find a single example of something like this. I have tried so many “Permissions" and multi-user examples from the realm.io.docs and every site multiple pages into Google, but everything is on how to create private realms or restrict additional users from seeing an existing realm, or they do not explain how to just create a user and let them access a realm in the Cloud. There are a few hundred objects in /Companies, so doing it by hand using Realm Studio is not practical. Could someone please explain how to hard code just a single global realm with two users?

This is really stupid that I’m having so much trouble with this, but I’m completely stumped. I don’t need the app to be adaptive, I don’t need any fancy UI, security, restrictions, none of that. I just need to be able to update some data from a separate entity--Realm Studio, a macOS app, an ios app that never leaves the computer-- whatever, so that the client iOS app can see and use the new data.

If someone is able to provide a solution, I’ll probably cry out of gratitude, I’m so exhausted and frustrated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am building an app with very similar requirements except I have one (1) writer and N readers. I have successfully setup a single user that can write to realm cloud and then subscribe to that Realm from N number of devices. However, I am trying to allow additional users to subscribe and have had no luck with permissions, etc., either.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you simply want one user to update and one user to retrieve and use the updated data. I suggest the following two cloud solutions:

**Firebase**

One solution could be to use a backend, say Firebase, that will be used by the one updating the Realm - [Jared Davidson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwVeP5BLGtA) has a decent tutorial that will get you started.

**Realm Platform Cloud**

Furthermore for a simplified and powerful solution, you could use Realm's own cloud service, [Realm Platform Cloud](https://realm.io/products/realm-platform), having a 30-day free trial followed by 30$/month.